# There exists a vector $\alpha$ s.t $f(T)(\alpha)=0$ then $f(T)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $T$ be a linear operator over a finite dimensional vector space $V$. Prove that there existir a vector $\alpha \in V$ with the follow property: "If $f$ is a polynomial and $f(T)\alpha =0$ then $f(T)=0$''.

Can you give me a hint about how to build this vector $\alpha$? and of course, why it works.

Comment: Is you vectorspace real, complex or general?

Comment: it is a general.

Comment: Let $f,g$ be coprime divisors of the minimal polynomial of $T$, let $\alpha,\beta \in V$ be such that $f,g$ respectively are the smallest-degree nonzero polynomials satisfying $f(T)\alpha=0$, $g(T)\beta=0$. Show that then $fg$ is the smallest-degree nonzero polynomial $h$ satisfying $h(T)(\alpha+\beta)=0$.